# Defining the order of loopback observers

Tags: node.js, loopback, observers

I'm currently writing a REST API in node.js using IBM's loopback. I'm running into an issue where the order of observers is relevant, and they are called in the wrong order.

My *Ticket* model has an **internal status** field. This status is stored in the database as a UUID. Somewhere in a large "metadata" file, the human name for each status is also defined. The same goes for the **external status** field.

Here are the relevant parts of `Ticket.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Ticket",
  "properties": {
    "internalStatusId": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "externalStatusId": {
      "type": "String"
    }
  }
}
```

I have written a generic mixin that can convert the human name of such a UUID field to the correct UUID. This mixin is used to allow clients to set a UUID field by its name (via a differently named field).

Here is a simplified version of the mixin:

```
// This observer is actually a simplification of the actual observer,
// which is more generic. It handles "name to id" mapping for any number
// of fields you can configure in the <model>.json file.
Model.observe('before save', function (ctx, next) {
  let data = ctx.isNewInstance ? ctx.instance : ctx.data;
  if (data.internalStatusName) {
    data.internalStatusId = internalStatusNameToIdMap[data.internalStatusName];
    delete data.internalStatusName;
  }
  next();
});
```

So if you send a `PUT` request to `/Tickets/1` with `{ "internalStatusName": "Closed" }` as body, this code will convert that to the correct UUID, put that in the `internalStatusId` field, and remove the `internalStatusName` field from the arguments.

Now, there is a business rule in the system: if the internal status is set to `Closed`, the external status also needs to be set to `Closed`. The code for that is located in `Ticket.js`, because it's not generic but only relevant for the *Ticket* model:

```
// This observer is located in Ticket.json.
// It makes sure that, when a ticket's internal status is set to Closed,
// the external status is also set to Closed.
Ticket.observe('before save', function (ctx, next) {
  let data = ctx.isNewInstance ? ctx.instance : ctx.data;
  if (data.internalStatusId === INTERNAL_STATUS_CLOSED_UUID) {
    data.externalStatusId = EXTERNAL_STATUS_CLOSED_UUID;
  }
  next();
});
```

The problem that I'm running into is that these two observers don't work well together, because they are invoked in the wrong order.

If I send `{ "internalStatusName": "Closed" }`:

- First the observer from `Ticket.js` is called. This checks if the `internalStatusId` field is set, to know if the external status needs to be updated. The `internalStatusId` is not present in the arguments, so the external status is not set.
- Second, the mixin observer is called. The internal status name is converted to the id.

This order is probably caused by loopback first loading the observers in `Ticket.js` and after that the mixin observers.

I could, of course, modify the second observer to look for both the `internalStatusId` *and* the `internalStatusName` fields. However, this leads to a significant duplication of code, especially because I have many of such business logic observers and also many UUID fields like this.

I've been looking for a way to tell loopback which order to run these observers in. Even a function as simple as `Model.observeFirst()` (this does not actually exist!) to put one or more observers at the front of the chain would solve this problem. I have not been able to find if this is possible, and if so, how.

How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loopback loads first the implementation of the model and only after this implementation of the mixins, and therefore the wrong order.
Loopback uses a standard system of subscriptions to the event. You can therefore use the prependListener to add the listener to the beginning.

```
// Puts first
Model.prependListener('before save', function (ctx, next) {
  let data = ctx.isNewInstance ? ctx.instance : ctx.data;
  if (data.internalStatusName) {
    data.internalStatusId = internalStatusNameToIdMap[data.internalStatusName];
    delete data.internalStatusName;
  }
  next();
});
```